# How to set up library with cmake on github

Tags: github, cmake

I'm learning cmake using the [tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html).
Would it be fine to build up a library similar to the tutorial for distribution on github?  In other words, distribute the library as a part of an example program repo?  A user would clone the repo,cmake, then make to see that the library works. Then later copy the library folder to his own project and use the repo's CMakeList.txt as a starting point for his use of the library?

Cmake is a great tool and I want to use it in a way that's easy for other people to use my libraries when I make them.

[Here's an example of what I'm looking to do.](https://github.com/lucidguppy/kip)

Comment: Like [this](https://github.com/gergap/helloworld)?

Comment: One more [candidate](https://github.com/rpavlik/cmake-modules) to be interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on voting for my comment I propose using already existed [project](https://github.com/gergap/helloworld).

Comment: It's a nice repo to have a bookmark to - I've modified my question to give an example of what I was looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

You may find these interesting:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html

Of course, most of it applies to CMake 2.8.12 and .11.